# Render Angular Material components with ComponentFactoryResolver

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, angular-material2, dynamic-compilation

I want to use ComponentFactoryResolver to dynamically create a component, I have read tutorials on how to achieve this (e.g. [this](https://blog.dmbcllc.com/dynamically-add-components-in-angular/)), but can't see how it's related to Material components.

Example - dynamically render md-select

I can see how to get the MdSelectModule, but not the component that's served from that module.
I need something like this:

`const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MdSelectComponent);`

How would I do this? I could create a wrapper component which just holds a single `<md-select>` and use that, but I'm interested to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

So to do this I did create a new component, and simply nested `<md-select>` inside it.

Still interested to see if there's a better way, but this is a solution.

Comment: is that what you ended up doing? I've been scouring the web but can't find a better solution either..

Comment: I think i did but I can't remember and abandoned the project some time ago. This has come on a long way in version 6 so have a read up - but they have to be declared as entry components, and im not sure you can do that with library components, you may be able to